# create json array in php for android

Tags: php, android, json

my php code for making a json array so far is

```
 $response[$x]=$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];
 $res2=array("names"=>$response);
 echo json_encode($res2);
```

where response is an array. This has as output

```
{"names":["Mario 1","Luigi 2","Mario 3"]}
```

which looks like a json array but when i try to retrieve the array in android by using

```
 json.getJSONArray("names");
```

I get a jsonexception saying "no values for names". What is wrong? Otherwise any suggestion on how to put the names on a jsonobject and retrive them in android.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String obj=JSONObject.quote(YourData);
    JSONArray lArray=new JSONArray(obj);
```

or simply Delete the prefix 'names'  `$res2=array("names"=>$response);` and you will retrive directelly your JsonArray like

```
    JSONArray lArray=new JSONArray(YouData);
```

Comment: Thanks. My code was actually correct. I made a mistake when requesting the json object. so I was not getting any object at the end. But I fixed it and I am getting the array now, going to delete this question.